# .NET XML Serialization error (There was an error reflecting type)

Tags: c#, xml-serialization

Yes I know very generic title, but I'm going to explain now.

Given the class definition below, can someone explain why I would be getting this exception when I invoke the Serialize() method.

{"There was an error reflecting type 'FNM.MISMO_3_0.FOREIGN_OBJECT'."}

{"Type of choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' is inconsistent with type of 'Items'. Please use array of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MISMO_3_0.ItemsChoiceType, MISMO_3_0, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]."}

Thank you,
Stephen

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Xml", "4.0.30319.225")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "http://www.mismo.org/residential/2009/schemas", IsNullable = true)]
public partial class FOREIGN_OBJECT
{

    private List<object> itemsField;

    private List<ItemsChoiceType> itemsElementNameField;

    private MISMOresourceLink typeField;

    private bool typeFieldSpecified;

    private string roleField;

    private string titleField;

    private string labelField;

    private string sequenceNumberField;

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer;

    public FOREIGN_OBJECT()
    {
        this.itemsElementNameField = new List<ItemsChoiceType>();
        this.itemsField = new List<object>();
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CharacterEncodingSetType", typeof(CharacterEncodingSetEnum), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("CharacterEncodingSetTypeOtherDescription", typeof(MISMOString), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("EXTENSION", typeof(EXTENSION), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("EmbeddedContentXML", typeof(MISMOXML), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MIMETypeIdentifier", typeof(MISMOIdentifier), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ObjectCreatedDatetime", typeof(MISMODatetime), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ObjectDescription", typeof(MISMOString), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ObjectEncodingType", typeof(ObjectEncodingEnum), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ObjectEncodingTypeOtherDescription", typeof(MISMOString), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ObjectName", typeof(MISMOString), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ObjectURI", typeof(string), DataType = "anyURI", Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("OriginalCreatorDigestValue", typeof(MISMOValue), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("REFERENCE", typeof(REFERENCE), Order = 0)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute("ItemsElementName")]
    public List<object> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName", Order = 1)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public List<ItemsChoiceType> ItemsElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")]
    public MISMOresourceLink type
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
    public bool typeSpecified
    {
        get
        {
            return this.typeFieldSpecified;
        }
        set
        {
            this.typeFieldSpecified = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")]
    public string role
    {
        get
        {
            return this.roleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.roleField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")]
    public string title
    {
        get
        {
            return this.titleField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.titleField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Qualified, Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink", DataType = "NMTOKEN")]
    public string label
    {
        get
        {
            return this.labelField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.labelField = value;
        }
    }

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute(DataType = "integer")]
    public string SequenceNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return this.sequenceNumberField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.sequenceNumberField = value;
        }
    }

    private static System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer Serializer
    {
        get
        {
            if ((serializer == null))
            {
                serializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(FOREIGN_OBJECT));
            }
            return serializer;
        }
    }

    #region Serialize/Deserialize
    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes current FOREIGN_OBJECT object into an XML document
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>string XML value</returns>
    public virtual string Serialize(System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = null;
        System.IO.MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
        try
        {
            memoryStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
            System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings xmlWriterSettings = new System.Xml.XmlWriterSettings();
            xmlWriterSettings.Encoding = encoding;
            System.Xml.XmlWriter xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(memoryStream, xmlWriterSettings);
            Serializer.Serialize(xmlWriter, this);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin);
            streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(memoryStream);
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((streamReader != null))
            {
                streamReader.Dispose();
            }
            if ((memoryStream != null))
            {
                memoryStream.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    public virtual string Serialize()
    {
        return Serialize(Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes workflow markup into an FOREIGN_OBJECT object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="xml">string workflow markup to deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Output FOREIGN_OBJECT object</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
    public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out FOREIGN_OBJECT obj, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        obj = default(FOREIGN_OBJECT);
        try
        {
            obj = Deserialize(xml);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool Deserialize(string xml, out FOREIGN_OBJECT obj)
    {
        System.Exception exception = null;
        return Deserialize(xml, out obj, out exception);
    }

    public static FOREIGN_OBJECT Deserialize(string xml)
    {
        System.IO.StringReader stringReader = null;
        try
        {
            stringReader = new System.IO.StringReader(xml);
            return ((FOREIGN_OBJECT)(Serializer.Deserialize(System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stringReader))));
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((stringReader != null))
            {
                stringReader.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Serializes current FOREIGN_OBJECT object into file
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">full path of outupt xml file</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if can serialize and save into file; otherwise, false</returns>
    public virtual bool SaveToFile(string fileName, System.Text.Encoding encoding, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        try
        {
            SaveToFile(fileName, encoding);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            exception = e;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public virtual bool SaveToFile(string fileName, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        return SaveToFile(fileName, Encoding.UTF8, out exception);
    }

    public virtual void SaveToFile(string fileName)
    {
        SaveToFile(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public virtual void SaveToFile(string fileName, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        System.IO.StreamWriter streamWriter = null;
        try
        {
            string xmlString = Serialize(encoding);
            streamWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(fileName, false, Encoding.UTF8);
            streamWriter.WriteLine(xmlString);
            streamWriter.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((streamWriter != null))
            {
                streamWriter.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Deserializes xml markup from file into an FOREIGN_OBJECT object
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="fileName">string xml file to load and deserialize</param>
    /// <param name="obj">Output FOREIGN_OBJECT object</param>
    /// <param name="exception">output Exception value if deserialize failed</param>
    /// <returns>true if this XmlSerializer can deserialize the object; otherwise, false</returns>
    public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, System.Text.Encoding encoding, out FOREIGN_OBJECT obj, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        exception = null;
        obj = default(FOREIGN_OBJECT);
        try
        {
            obj = LoadFromFile(fileName, encoding);
            return true;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            exception = ex;
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out FOREIGN_OBJECT obj, out System.Exception exception)
    {
        return LoadFromFile(fileName, Encoding.UTF8, out obj, out exception);
    }

    public static bool LoadFromFile(string fileName, out FOREIGN_OBJECT obj)
    {
        System.Exception exception = null;
        return LoadFromFile(fileName, out obj, out exception);
    }

    public static FOREIGN_OBJECT LoadFromFile(string fileName)
    {
        return LoadFromFile(fileName, Encoding.UTF8);
    }

    public static FOREIGN_OBJECT LoadFromFile(string fileName, System.Text.Encoding encoding)
    {
        System.IO.FileStream file = null;
        System.IO.StreamReader sr = null;
        try
        {
            file = new System.IO.FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(file, encoding);
            string xmlString = sr.ReadToEnd();
            sr.Close();
            file.Close();
            return Deserialize(xmlString);
        }
        finally
        {
            if ((file != null))
            {
                file.Dispose();
            }
            if ((sr != null))
            {
                sr.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Clone method
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a clone of this FOREIGN_OBJECT object
    /// </summary>
    public virtual FOREIGN_OBJECT Clone()
    {
        return ((FOREIGN_OBJECT)(this.MemberwiseClone()));
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Please try to change 'List<object> Items' to 'object[] Items'.

Answer (score 8):

The multiple elements in a `XmlChoiceIdentifierAttribute` is supported only with the ChoiceIdentifier being an array not a generic list.

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ItemsElementName", Order = 1)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlIgnoreAttribute()]
public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName
{
    // ...
}
```

The error is confusing because it's assuming that as Items is array-like (A list) and your choice identifier isn't an array you missed the array qualifier before the type of the choice of identifier. But it isn't the case, so the suggestion is completely misleading.

**Note: Seeing the code (from the microsoft source server) in theory Items don't need to be an array... in practice the generation of the temporary serialization class completely explode because List.Length isn't public (it's implemented explicitly)**